# Background color with transparent border-image

Tags: google-chrome, background, png, border, css

I try to build a nice box with only 1 image and 1 div. Here is my code:

```
border-width: 14px;
-moz-border-image:url(box.png) 14 round;
-webkit-border-image:url(box.png) 14 round;
-o-border-image:url(box.png) 14 round;
border-image:url(box.png) 14 round;
```

And an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZHKbn/

In Safari & Firefox, the background of the box is white, but in Chrome, its transparent.

Which browser is correct? I need the white background version, is there a fix to get this working in Chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this suffice?

I added an inner div with the background color. seems to work in chrome and firefox now.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZHKbn/2/

This works in chrome, but does not work in firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZHKbn/7/

Ok, final one. Works in chrome and firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZHKbn/8/

```
border-width: 14px;
-moz-border-image:url(http://cl.ly/041l44390l002l2j1307/box.png) 14 round;
-webkit-border-image:url(http://cl.ly/041l44390l002l2j1307/box.png) 14 fill round;
-o-border-image:url(http://cl.ly/041l44390l002l2j1307/box.png) 14 round;
border-image:url(http://cl.ly/041l44390l002l2j1307/box.png) 14 fill round;
```

​

Comment: Well, thanks, its a solution, but i try to avoid adding an extra div to the syntax. Works in firefox and opera for me without the inner div, so i only have problem with chrome, i guess it's chrome a bug? Strange, because safari is webkit too. Anyway, if i don't get a better answer, i will accept yours:)

Comment: yes, i tried (and still trying) to do it a better way, but I havnt found one. im not sure its a chrome bug or not, that depends on whats the "correct" behavior of border-image is. If there even is a "correct" one yet. is it really correct to decide that the background of the div should be white even though there's nothing in the css that says so? That I dont know... but I would also prefer a solution without another div ofcrouse..

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/ this link describes the "quirk" of actually filling the div with the center of the border image. and that the default should be to discard it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will check this in IE10, fingers crossed:)